# mysql get 50 percent from member table

Tags: mysql

Hi everyone i have question.

I have table name **Members** on my database end 
i wont select 50 percent women
end 50 percent man.

I do not know how to perform the query

```
SELECT * FROM `members` WHERE gender = 'FEMALE' OR gender = 'MALE'
```

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to rank your rows and create partition by gender ,

something like that:

```
SELECT @row_num := IF(@prev_value=GENDER,@row_num+1,1) AS RowNumber
       user_id,
       Gender,
       @prev_value := GENDER
  FROM Person,
      (SELECT @row_num := 1) x,
      (SELECT @prev_value := '') y
  ORDER BY Gender,user_id
```

and than you can pull the number of users you need, for example if you need 100 users you can running when RowNumber<=50,

you will get 50 users from each gender (if you have enough records in the table).

you can play with the order to change the ordering for example add age or other fields

Answer (score 1):

This will get you 20 records, equally male and female

```
(SELECT * FROM members WHERE gender = 'FEMALE' limit 10)
union all
(SELECT * FROM members WHERE gender = 'MALE' limit 10)
```

Comment: ...assuming there are adequate numbers of both genders